# EagerLoading on category pages with different product types

Tags: templating, plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce2, eager-loading

I have a category template like so;

```
{% extends '_layouts/_site' %}

{% set products = craft.products
  .with( [
  'department',
  'productImage',
  'finish',
  'pcd',
  'variants',
  'thread',
  'seat',
  'hexHead'
])
  .orderBy('title asc')
  .relatedTo(category)
  .all() %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="flex flex-wrap px-12">
    {% for product in products %}
      {% switch product.type %}

      {% case product.type %}
        {% include "shop/products/_teasers/" ~ product.type %}

      {% default %}
        none

      {% endswitch %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

At the moment this is eagerLoading all the different fields across all the different products and this is only 2 product types. There will be more to follow.

For Example.
Wheel Spacers only require these fields:
'department',
'productImage',
'pcd',
'variants',

Bolts only require these fields:
'department',
'productImage',
'variants',
'thread',
'seat',
'hexHead',
'finish'

So depending on the product this adds a few additional calls. Probably not an issue in this instance, but I wondered if there is a way to only EagerLoad the right fields for the right products?

Thanks,